# Redshift : Coalesce Can't Work As Expected

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We're complementing null value to all zero value like '00' on Redshift.
Sometimes, I found coalesce function can't work as we expected.
If we use case and len, it can work fine as follows;

```
-- not work
SELECT coalesce(code_a, '00') FROM test;  --> code_a returns nothing. 

-- works fine
SELECT case when len(code_a)=0 then '00' else code_a end as code_a FROM test;
  --> code_a returns 00 as expected.
```

So far, I have no idea why coalesce can't work. Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `as code_a` after `coalesce(code_a, '00')`

Comment: `COALESCE` will return the first non-null value. I don't think an empty string is equivalent to a NULL. What do you mean by "code_a returns nothing"?

Comment: @ John Rotenstein  Many thanks for your help again. Yes, you're right. It seems original data contains empty string...  As Gordon Linoff answer, nullif helps this case (And I'm wondering if any copy option like 'NULL AS' can convert empty string to null, and coalesce works anytime)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica thanks ! I decided nullif as  Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between `''` and `NULL` -- and I should note that this is *expected*.

You can solve this in one of two ways:

```
coalese(nullif(code_a, ''), '00')
```

or using a `case` expression:

```
(case when code_a <> '' then code_a else '00' end)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt and useful answer. I tried nullif  and it's working fine. I really appreciated it. Have a wonderful weekend:)